# Last defined prototype function always runs on object initialization

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor, prototype

Given the following code (StoriesMap.js)...

```
// Initalization; Creates Map
var StoriesMap = function StoriesMap( id, location, tileset ) {
    this.map = L.map( id ).setView([ location.lat, location.lon ], location.zoom);

    // Add inital points to map
    this.populate( location );

    // Redraw on map movement
    this.map.on("viewreset", function( event ) {
        var location = {
            lat: event.target._animateToCenter.lat,
            lon: event.target._animateToCenter.lng,
            zoom: event.target._animateToZoom
        };

        this.redraw( location );
    });

    var mapTiles = L.tileLayer( tileset.url, { attribution: tileset.attribution, minZoom: 4, maxZoom: 12 } ).addTo( this.map );
}


// Put some points on the map
StoriesMap.prototype.populate = function populate( location ) {
    var priority = location.zoom - 3;

    if ( typeof points === "object" ) {
        var buffer = [];

        for ( var i in points ) {
            var point = points[i];

            if ( point.priority <= priority ) {
                var circle = L.circle([ point.lat, point.lon ], 100000, {
                    color: '#f03', fillColor: '#f03', fillOpacity: 0.5
                }).addTo( this.map );
            }
        }
    }

}

// Filters map contents
StoriesMap.prototype.filter = function filter( map, location ) {
    console.log( "filter" );
}

// Redraws map points
StoriesMap.prototype.redraw = function redraw( map, location ) {
    console.log ( this.map )

    for ( var i in map._layers ) {
        if ( map._layers[i]._path != undefined ) {
            try {
                map.removeLayer( map._layers[i] );
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.log("problem with " + e + map._layers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

StoriesMap.prototype.fake = function fake() {
    console.log("Always Called when object is Initialized");
}
```

When I run (from my html):

```
 var map = new Map();
```

I always get:

```
Always Called when object is Initialized
```

in my console. For whatever reason, my last defined prototype is being treated like a constructor, and I'm not sure why. I don't want that function to run when I initialize my object, is it assumed to be a constructor? This has happened to me before and my normal reaction has been to create a last prototype function with the name "fake" and to leave it empty, but what is the proper resolution to this issue?

Comment: Show us `/* code */`.   I can't reproduce that.  http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/arMV3/

Comment: Do you have a stray `()` later?

Comment: So you're telling us that with just that code, you get the message logged? Honestly? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) @SLaks: Good point. Probably has an IIFE after the last prototyped method.

Comment: And no that's not the case. may be there is some other code that calls your last prototype so please show us your commented code as requested above

Comment: @BlueSkies I mean strange the behaviour he described, not that isn't happening(what is expected).

Comment: Is that the end of your file? Is there code anything after `fake`? Try putting a semicolon at the end of the `fake` function expression.

Comment: Code added. not making any other calls to it.

Comment: That is the end of my file. Nothing after fake.

Comment: Are you using any minification or compilation tools that might place a `(...)` expression after that line? Can you `console.log(arguments)` inside of `fake` to see how it is being called? (Also a `debugger;` statement might help if you have Firebug or Chrome dev tools open at the time the function runs.) Can you add `return 0` to the function expression and verify whether `map.fake` actually is a function or that `map.fake` is the return value of that function?

Comment: Did you do what apsillers suggested and put a semicolon at the end? The code you provided simply does not do what you claim. But it could if it's joined with another file.

Comment: blue skies - put that down as an answer. semicolon at the end of the file fixed it. not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has other code concatenated to it at some point (probably during some kind of build process or minificaiton). The other code begins with a parenthesized statement:

```
StoriesMap.prototype.fake = function fake() {
    console.log("Always Called when object is Initialized");
}

// start of other code...
(...);
```

However, JavaScript reads this as:

```
StoriesMap.prototype.fake = function fake() {
    console.log("Always Called when object is Initialized");
}(...);
```

So `StoriesMap.prototype.fake` is not equal to the function, but instead the function is *immediately invoked*, using the parenthesized expression as an argument. `StoriesMap.prototype.fake` is set to the *return value* of the immediately invoked function.

Simply add a semicolon at the end of the function expression, and this won't happen, because the parenthesized statement and the function will be separated by a semicolon:

```
StoriesMap.prototype.fake = function fake() {
    console.log("Always Called when object is Initialized");
};
(...);
```

JavaScript's *automatic semicolon insertion* only occurs when the lack of a semicolon would cause a violation of the language grammar. See the bottom of [ES 7.9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.2) for an example similar to this one:

> The source
>
> ```
> a = b + c
> (d + e).print()
> ```
>
> is not transformed by automatic semicolon insertion, because the parenthesised expression that begins the second line can be interpreted as an argument list for a function call:
>
> ```
> a = b + c(d + e).print()
> ```
>
> In the circumstance that an assignment statement must begin with a left parenthesis, it is a good idea for the programmer to provide an explicit semicolon at the end of the preceding statement rather than to rely on automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Years into JS, the "automatic semicolon insertion" still can be confusing.